# Touchpad behavior changed drasticall - tap-to-click won't work, and scrolling is less effective

Tags: cinnamon, touchpad

I'm running Cinnamon on Debian Testing on a Dell XPS 13.

Sometime over the last couple days, touchpad operation changed quite significantly:

- tap-to-click stopped working entirely (I've tried toggling it in the settings, no effect)
- scrolling is a lot less "effective". Used to be I'd swipe and the page would scroll for a while after my fingers left the touchpad. Now it scrolls a lot less.

Does anyone know what may have caused this, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I found the fix here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/linux.debian.bugs.dist/823843/linux.debian.bugs.dist/HWGqZr43lQU/NBMDkaKxBAAJ

I'm under Debian x86_64 Stretch with Cinnamon

Comment: Thank you! Following these steps solved my issue :) Could you please edit to put the solution into your answer (lest it succumb to eventual link-rot, etc)?

Comment: The solution linked to suggests doing the following (as root): `mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` followed by `cp /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`. Worked for me.